# Generate Code First Model Classes from Existing Database Programatically

Tags: entity-framework

I've looked at EdmGen.exe but it seems that it doesn't support generating code first model classes from an existing database. Everywhere I look tells me to use the wizard in Visual Studio but I'm trying to automate this process. Is there a command line tool I can use to generate code first model classes and the context class from an existing database? I want this to be part of my continuous integration build process so it must be fully automatable.

Comment: For me EdmGen works. I never used it in CI so usually I make changes after first generation but I think it could work without changes. There are also other generators and also EdmGen2 (open source) but EdmGen should work...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any command line tool available that does what you're asking, but it's possible to build your own tool that uses the schema views to generate the code.

For example, you would use the `sys.objects` view to derive the classes, and the `sys.columns` view to derive the fields within those classes.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx

Comment: That is an option, but I'd rather use Entity Framework code so I know there won't be any runtime issues with the classes not matching the schema

Comment: @reggaeguitar I understand, but I don't think there's any such tool available. Why not make it for the world!